# insert view with dynamic template

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to inset a dynamic view(to make a tooltip) that have a dynamic template to render in so inside im creating and appending a view to the parent element. I get following error

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You specified the templateName ... for <(subclass of Ember.View):ember1104>, but it did not exist.
```

the template exist and i can add the view in other templates with view helper. Here is my parent view example :

```
App.ModalOverlayView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'modal_overlay/layout'

didInsertElement: ->
  textView = Ember.View.extend({templateName: @get('templateToShow')}).create()
  textView.appendTo(@$('.text'))
```

Comment: what value does this `@get('templateToShow')` return?

Comment: it returns a template name that is valid and exits. If i put the template name directly here the result and error stays the same

Answer (score 3):

Bassically I did what you want in sections of a page.

So what I did was had a container view for the view that I wanted to be render. For example:

```
{{view MainApp.AppContainerView elementId="appContainerView"}}
```

Then, when I need a espefic templete to be render inside that container, I loded it by ajax. For example, if I wanted to show the template "xpto", I had this template in a file called "xpto.handlebars". So I did this:

```
 view = Ember.View.create({
                willInsertElement : function(){
                    var isLoaded = this.isLoaded;
                    if(!isLoaded){
                        getTemplate("/app_dev/templates/" + templateName + ".handlebars", this);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Where "templateName" its the name of your template that you want to show, in this case its "xpto", and "getTemplate" its an ajax function to get the template:

```
function getTemplate(path, view){
    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        //cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var templateName = "";
            $(data).filter('script[type="text/x-handlebars"]').each(function() {
                templateName = $(this).attr('data-template-name');
                Ember.TEMPLATES[templateName] = Ember.Handlebars.compile($(this).html());
            });
            if(view != null){
                view.set("templateName", templateName);
                view.rerender();
            }

        }               
    });    
}
```

and finally I did this to add the view into the container:

```
    var containerView = Em.View.views['appContainerView']; 
    if(containerView == undefined)
        return;
    var temp =  containerView.toArray(); 
    if(temp.length > 0)
        containerView.unshiftObject();
    containerView.addObject(view);
```

I hope this can help you,

Juanito

Comment: thanks i've managed to do it differently i'm using generic view in template with custom template name wich meets my needs. But Thank you a lot for the answer it gave some new ideas ;)